# Probability - dice

Tags: probability

(a) What is the probability that if there are $4$ dice thrown, there will be two same values gained and two different ones? Is this solution correct?
$P = \frac{6\cdot1\cdot5\cdot4\cdot6}{6^4}$

(b) Would the solution be different if we assumed that there were $4$ different (for example in the way of colour) dice thrown?

(c) If we throw $4$ dice, we might gain $6^4$ different results. These may be composed as:

1. we gain all the values different ($6\cdot5\cdot4\cdot3 = 360$);
2. we gain all the values same ($6$);
3. we gain two same values and two different values ($6\cdot1\cdot5\cdot4\cdot6 = 720$);
4. we gain three same values and one differing ($6\cdot5\cdot4 = 120$).
   If counted, we would get this result: $1206$ out of $1296$? What possibilities are remaining?
   Would the solution of the task be different if there were $4$ different (for example in the way of colour) dice thrown?

(d) If we cut something $10$ metres long, what is the probability that there will be two parts having more than $2$ metres? Is this solution correct?
$P = \frac{6m}{10m}$

Thank you!

Comment: You may want to split the question in different parts. I suggest separating a-b-c from d.

Comment: Welcome at Math.SE. I advice you not to ask so many questions in one. Start with one question. The answer on it can give you a lead to find the other answers yourself, and - if not - then you can always post them in a new question.

Comment: The plural is *dice* and the singular *die*. Changing the colours does not affect the probabilities as you do not have a Bose-Einstein state. You have misses "two pairs of numbers" and "all four the same". Cutting the stuff is a different question.

Answer (score 0):

For a, it looks like you are choosing the first die (6 ways), forcing the second to match (1 way), choosing the third (5 ways), choosing the fourth (4 ways), and choosing where the pair goes (6 ways).   This is fine.
For b, how can painting the dice matter?

For c, the fact that they do not sum to 1296 says something is wrong.  For 4, you have required that the first three differ, so have missed 1124 as a possibility and have not required the fourth to match one of the first three.

Comment: Thank you!
(a) My logic is: I have 6 possible values assigned to first die, than I must choose the same value on the second die, and the remaining dice may be chosen in 5*4 ways (they must differ from each other and also from the first two dice). I must count that the two same dice may be chosen from all 4 dice in 4C2 ways.
(b) I do not think it matters, but I need to be sure. Teacher said that.

Comment: Sorry, I misread and thought in a you wanted two pairs.  See update.

Comment: @Curve: you seem to be the proud owner of two separate accounts, this prevents you from responding to comments and editing to provide clarification for your original question. Please first _register_ your account and then [go here](http://math.stackexchange.com/contact) to request your two (or more) accounts be merged.