# Dice - throwing

Tags: probability, dice

(a) What is the probability that if there are 4 dice thrown, there will be two same values gained and two different ones? Is this solution correct? P = 6 ⋅ 1 ⋅ 5 ⋅ 4 ⋅ 6 = 720.
My logic is: I have 6 possible values assigned to first die, than I must choose the same value on the second die, and the remaining dice may be chosen in $5\times4$ ways (they must differ from each other and also from the first two dice). I must count that the two same dice may be chosen from all 4 dice in 4C2 ways.
(b) If we throw 4 dices, we might gain 6^4 different results. These may be composed as:
we gain all the values different (6 ⋅ 5 ⋅ 4 ⋅ 3 = 360);
we gain all the values same (6);
we gain two same values and two different values (6 ⋅ 1 ⋅ 5 ⋅ 4 ⋅ 6 = 720);
we gain three same values and one differing (6 ⋅ 5 ⋅ 4 = 120). If counted, we would get this result: 1206 out of 1296? What possibilities are remaining?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/640535/probability-dices/640548#640548, which has the same user name but a different account, it seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we start by assuming the second dice matches the first and the third and fourth are both different the probability would be

$$\frac{1}{6} \cdot \frac{5}{6} \cdot \frac{4}{6} = \frac{5}{54}$$

But we don't care about the order. How many ways can we have two same and two different?

Lets list them SSDD, SDSD, SDDS, DSSD, DSDS, DDSS. So we can multiply this by 6 and the answer is:

$$
6 \cdot \frac{5}{54} = \frac{5}{9}
$$

Comment: Thank you, but what about the second part - part (b)?

Comment: I suggest you ask that as a separate question and remove it from this one. But one possibility you have missed is two pairs say 6611 or 2233 in any order.  I can't think of any others.

Answer (score 0):

1 * 1/6 * 5/6 * 4/6 = 0.09259259... = 1/108

Comment: No, you are assuming the first two thrown must match.  But a roll of 1231 satisfies the question and is not counted here.

Comment: I am assuming 1 (1*1/6) dice has to match and the other 2 dices has to be different than the other 2 (5/6*4/6). If you're multiplicating them all it doesn't matter in what order. In your case it would be: 1*5/6*4/6*1/6, can you tell me the difference?

Comment: If you think of throwing the dice sequentially, your calculation requires that specifically the first two dice thrown are the pair, because you force the second die to match the first.

Comment: @Ajaxkevi True 1*1/6*5/6*4/6 = 1*5/6*4/6*1/6 but both of these satisfy the question and so do a few more but they all need to be counted.  See my answer.